# Invalid filename. TitleContainer.OpenStream requires a relative URI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xna

I have got this error in WPF application.

> Invalid filename. [TitleContainer.OpenStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.titlecontainer.openstream.aspx) requires a relative URI.

```
pic_texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, TitleContainer.OpenStream(@"\Images\performer.png"));
```

I have tried also

```
@"/WpfControlLibrary1;component/Images/performer.png"
```

No success...

if I do like this

```
  pic_texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, TitleContainer.OpenStream(@"performer.png"));
```

and put file in the root

The error is:

> Error loading "performer.png". File not found.

Any clue?

Thank you!

P.S. I am sure file is OK.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

This post https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/xna-am-i-screwing-up-the-loadcontent-for-texture2d doesn't help also.

Comment: Could you try it without the leading backslash (or slash)?

Comment: @NikoDrašković Yes I did I just put file into the root of the and have an error: "Error loading "performer.png". File not found."

Comment: You've probably already checked - but are you absolutely sure the file is there? If you're adding it through Visual Studio - make sure you have `Copy to Output: Copy if newer` selected in the files properties. I only get the "relative URI" error if I include the leading `/` - otherwise file loads just fine.

Comment: @NikoDrašković Yes I am sure have a look at the updated question please.

Comment: Following your latest update - I guess that the problem might be a WPF thing. I can only think of an alternative - `FileInfo.OpenRead(..)`, though I'm not sure if that would work with WP7 or Xbox.

Comment: @Peretz inside your project should be a binary file, and inside the binary file should be a debug file, which should have your actual application in it.  Open that directiory in Windows explorer, and check if "Images\Performer.png" is there.

Comment: @SamIam Yes. I did like this I put this file everywhere I could. Nothing good... :(

Comment: @Peretz did you check using **windows explorer** (not in visual studio)

Comment: @Peretz Could it be that you're trying to load `performer.png` and your filename is `Performer.png` (with capital **P**)? :)

Comment: @Peretz  I've edited my answer to include some debugging instructions.  Could you try those out and tell me what you find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm partially guessing here, but try

```
pic_texture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, TitleContainer.OpenStream(@"Images\performer.png"));
```

without the first `\`

**Debugging**

In your program, add these lines  **immidiately before** the line where your error happens.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("myUniqueFile.txt", FileMode.Create);
fs.Close();
```

make sure you have

```
using System.IO
```

at the top of the code file.

Once you've done that, Search your computer for `"myUniqueFile.txt"` and tell me in the comments  where you've found it.

Comment: @Peretz are you getting the same error?, or is the error different?

Comment: @Peretz okay, try this:  right click on `performer.png`, and then select the build action to **none** and set the "copy to output directory" to **copy if newer**

Comment: @Peretz  this will ensure that the file is in the folder within your binary directory

Comment: Thanks!! I have got it under ...WpfApplication1\bin\x86\Debug

Comment: @Peretz what else is in `WpfApplication1\bin\x86\Debug`?  is your `Images` folder there?

Comment: @Peretz on that note, did you change the properties of `performer.png` in your solution explorer as both niko and I suggested?

Comment: @SamIam He was trying to load `performer.png`, and the screenshots have the file as `Performer.png`, so that was probably it. Those bugs are downright impossible to find if you've looked at the code for hours :)

Answer (score 1):

In VisualStudio, right-click 'performer.png' file, go to 'Properties', change 'Copy to Output Directory' to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.